# How to display a "scorecard" (a single number) in databricks dashboard

Tags: databricks

I'm building a dashboard with Databricks and I have a cell when I'm doing the sum of an entire column. The result is a simple number. How can I add it to my dashboard as a widget?

For example how can I display this in a databricks dashboard `print(3+4)`?

Comment: Can you please share a example for better understanding

Comment: are you asking about Databricks SQL dashboards, or dashboards created from notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so apart from `display` and `displayHTML` functions support visualizations in databricks. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/visualizations/